# What's the difference in session manager and session container in zend, which one is better?

Tags: php, session, cookies, zend-framework2

In my application I want to use session and cookies. On reading about session I came to know that in two ways I can implement session one is by session management and one is by using containers, using containers seems to be easy. I want to know which one is better or both are same and I am missing something. I want to use session and cookies both, can anyone have some source code or coding examples where session and cookies both have been used ? I don't know how to send the cookies to get the session values and how to use these values in my view files(js and phtml). Following is the code for session manager reffered from zend documentation:

```
return array(
    'session' => array(
        'config' => array(
            'class' => 'Zend\Session\Config\SessionConfig',
            'options' => array(
                'name' => 'myapp',
            ),
        ),
        'storage' => 'Zend\Session\Storage\SessionArrayStorage',
        'validators' => array(
            'Zend\Session\Validator\RemoteAddr',
            'Zend\Session\Validator\HttpUserAgent',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Do I need to place this code in my application.config.php file?

Answer (score 1):

Session Container used for working with session DATA.

Session Manager used for work with session LOGIC (e.g. start/close).

> Do I need to place this code in my application.config.php file?

Yes, in [ZF2 docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.manager.html#initializing-the-session-manager) wroted:

> The following illustrates how you may configure session manager by setting options in your local or global config:

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, any views on cookies ?

Comment: Cookies in ZF readable from `Request`, to example(from controller) - `$this->getRequest()->getCookie()->cookieName`.
Writing by using `Response`: `$this->getResponse()->getCookie()->cookieName = $cookieValue`

Comment: This operations you must do in controller, not in a view. View sholuld not work with request and response.

Comment: to access the session variables in js files, I need to pass these variables to view, then create some js variables in phtml file and use them later in js file, am I right ?

Comment: Do u have any application where you have implemented session and cookies? because its very easy to understand from code.